# Unable to access field in entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to create a sample EAR, maven project and I have almost everything working but for some reason, there is a problem with my entity class. In my database, I have a many to one relationship and it's been a pain trying to join the column with the other table in my Entity class. I've searched for sometime and I have not come up with anything. I would appreciate some assistance in this area.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the "city" database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="\"city\"")
@NamedQuery(name="City.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM City c")
public class City extends com.dozie.example.util.Entity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="\"id\"")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="\"country_id\"")
    private int countryId;

    @Column(name="\"name\"")
    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Country
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="\"country_id\"", referencedColumnName="\"id\"")
        })
    private Country country;

    public City() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCountryId() {
        return this.countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(int countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

and for my other Entity class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * The persistent class for the "country" database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="\"country\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c")
public class Country extends com.dozie.example.util.Entity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<City> cities;

    public Country() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="\"id\"")
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="\"name\"")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to City
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
    public Set<City> getCities() {
        return this.cities;
    }

    public void setCities(Set<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public City addCity(City city) {
        getCities().add(city);
        city.setCountry(this);

        return city;
    }

    public City removeCity(City city) {
        getCities().remove(city);
        city.setCountry(null);

        return city;
    }

}
```

and here's the script for my database table which is a Postgres database

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  country_id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT city_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT city_country_fk FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
      REFERENCES country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT city_name_idx UNIQUE (name)
)

CREATE TABLE country
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT country_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT country_name_idx UNIQUE (name)
)
```

When I have my server running I get this error message

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   cookbook-entities] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical
>   name: "id" in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(country) and its related
>   supertables and secondary tables  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:552)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:257)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1446)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1351)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1733)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
>     ... 38 more

When I try updating the join Column in my City entity not to include referenceColumnName I get a different error saying the physical name is different from the logical name. 
Also I noticed in the Entity classes I cannot name my field without putting them in quotes (I don't know if that's a normal behavior) I'm thinking this might have something to do with my problem but I have tried to do without the quotes and I error's whenever that happens.

I'd appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Why do you quote your table and field names. Can you not simply do `@Table(name="country")` and `@Column(name="id")`? This, by the way, is unnecessary if the object field and the table field have the exact same name and same for table names.

Comment: Yeah when I try doing that, I get compile errors. And I found it quite odd as well cause I haven't seen that before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding double quotes everywhere. You shouldn't. For example,

```
 @Table(name="\"city\"")
```

should be

```
@Table(name="city")
```

and

```
@Column(name="\"id\"")
```

should be

```
@Column(name="id")
```

and

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="\"country_id\"", referencedColumnName="\"id\"")
    })
```

should simply be

```
@JoinColumn(name="country_id")
```

Comment: Yeah when I try doing that, I get compile errors. And I found it quite odd as well cause I haven't seen that before

Comment: Then post the exact and complete compilation error.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you meant there. Anyway, I generated the entity using the eclipse automated feature that generates Entities from tables. So I'm not sure why this should be happening

Comment: You're telling us that not quoting the names in the annotations caused compilation errors. Don't you think that being able to read the error message you got from the compiler might help identifying what error you had in the code? If you go to the doctor, you don't just tell him "I'm sick, please cure me". You describe the symptoms, the locations where it hurts, etc. Error messages from the compiler are intended to be read, to identify the cause and location of the error in the code.

Comment: I understand that and I wouldn't spend a lot of time and just a basic compilation error. When I don't have the quotes it says the table doesn't exist so I thought maybe it might have to do with the integration with a different database because I have tried the same example with a different database and it worked.

And I have looked over my database table to make sure I did not use quotes in creating the table or any of the fields so I don't understand why the code cannot recognize the name without the quotes

Comment: That's not a compilation error. That's Eclipse trying to help you (but confusing you instead) and not finding a table with that name in the database associated (or not) with the project. Ignore the error.